# How to install a package that contains Ubuntu kernel debug symbols?

Tags: kernel, software-installation

The default Ubuntu kernel `-generic` package doesn't seem to have symbols in it.

I'm trying to avoid compile a kernel with debug info manually.

Does Ubuntu provide a package with kernel debug symbols?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. First create a `ddebs.list` using:

   ```sh
   echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
   ```
2. Then add the GPG key for `ddebs.ubuntu.com`:

   ```sh
   wget -O - http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/dbgsym-release-key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Then run:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Then install the symbols package using:

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install linux-image-`uname -r`-dbgsym
   ```

   This is rather huge (>680MB), so prepare for a wait while you download it.

<sup>I use the Linux kernel debug symbols for tools like `systemtap` on the kernel.</sup>

Comment: `apt-cache search dbgsym` returns `pkg-create-dbgsym` only, was it in some other repository?

Comment: @warl0ck Yes, the `-dbgsym` packages are in special repositories that you must enable, to install them. [This explains how](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash#Debug_Symbol_Packages).

Comment: I've now updated the post to clarify how to do that.

Comment: step `apt-get update` results in a warning message: `W: GPG error: http://ddebs.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ECDCAD72428D7C01`, that is why I am extending this with a solution for that case.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym=3.13.0-49.83
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic-dbgsym
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic-dbgsym'`

Comment: Step for adding GPG key is crucial and should succeed in order for download step of debug info packages to work. Should see message like `public key "Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key <ubuntu-archive@lists.ubuntu.com>" imported 
` . If it says "unchanged" status then the download will fail.

Comment: I needed the additional fix from dragosb's answer. 
(Not tested myself, but bbb31's answer should work on its own.)

Answer (score 9):

I tried [Colin Ian King](https://askubuntu.com/users/26614/colin-ian-king)'s answer and it did not work for me. I found out I must add two extra lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list`

Edit the file via

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
```

and add the two lines below

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Replace `trusty` with your version that you get when you execute

```
lsb_release -cs
```

Comment: This works to me!

Comment: I have to add only `deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse`  for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 9):

[For 16.04+](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap#Where_to_get_debug_symbols_for_kernel_X.3F):

GPG key import

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C8CAB6595FDFF622
```

Add repository config

```
codename=$(lsb_release -c | awk  '{print $2}')
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list << EOF
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}      main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-updates  main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/ ${codename}-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
EOF

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```

(credit to [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages#Getting_-dbgsym.ddeb_packages))