# Kernel custom building not working due to missing "binary-generic" recipe

Tags: kernel, compiling, debian, debug

I am on **Ubuntu 18.04** and I am trying to build my own kernel by [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Systemtap) and [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel).

Unfortunately the command:

```
AUTOBUILD=1 fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch skipdbg=false
```

Give me this error:

```
dh binary-headers
dh: Unknown sequence binary-headers (choose from: binary binary-arch binary-indep build build-arch build-indep clean install install-arch install-indep)
debian/rules:35: recipe for target 'binary-headers' failed
make: *** [binary-headers] Error 2
```

I suspect the guide is not updated, and I searched a lot about **rules** script recipies list, but I did not find anything useful.

Could somebody help me?

Thank you!

**Edit 1** The allowed recipies are `binary binary-arch binary-indep build build-arch build-indep clean install install-arch install-indep` but with these does not yet produce a kernel with embedded debug symbols.

**Edit 2** Debian rules are stored into `/usr/src/linux-source-{KERNEL-VERSION}/debian/rules.d` and into `0-common-vars.mk` you can find all the allowed switches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Debug Symbols (dbgsym) of unmodified kernel then just download them from the official repository, as documented in these:

- [How to install a package that contains Ubuntu kernel debug symbols?](https://askubuntu.com/a/197057/26246)
- [Ubuntu Wiki - Debug Symbol Packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages)

Otherwise for any kernel from other sources (as Debian package).

- [Ubuntu Wiki - Build Your Own Kernel: Debug Symbols](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel#Debug_Symbols)

  All you need to do is just install `pkg-config-dbgsym` package and add `skipdbg=false` flag to Debian make file (`debian/rules`)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pkg-config-dbgsym
  LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules clean
  LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch skipdbg=false
  ```

  **Important Note** `clean` command here is a must after changing config, adding flags or missed to install some build dependencies. So for each try, you need to run clean command, `make` will reconfigure the build tree with updated and current settings.