# There is no kernel dbgsym package for my Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, 22.04, 22.10

I wanted to download the kernel dbgsym package for my Ubuntu 22.04.

Followed the answers to this:

[How to install a package that contains Ubuntu kernel debug symbols?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197016/how-to-install-a-package-that-contains-ubuntu-kernel-debug-symbols)

But I still get:

```
 Unable to locate package linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic-dbgsym
```

When I try to get the dbgsym package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-`uname -r`-dbgsym
```

This is also the content of my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list` file:

```
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

So what should I do? I need to debug this Ubuntu 22.04, and I'm fine with doing whatever to it as it's a test machine and I just need to debug my driver in it.

**EDIT1**: I even did a upgrade to 22.10, to see if it resolves the issue, but no luck:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-`uname -r`-dbgsym

E: Unable to locate package linux-image-5.19.0-26-generic-dbgsym
```

(And I obviously did a apt-get update after the upgrade, and also the jammy repositories were already converted to kintetic)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages, the Ubuntu project maintains a Debugginfod server. GDB and other debuginfo consumer applications support out-of-the-box use. You can also get more information through this page https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-debuginfod .

But if you have to use dbgsym package, just following https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash#Non-built-in_debug_symbol_packages_.28.2A-dbgsym.29

Comment: This did not helped.